# How to redirect to the 404 Not Found Page in the app folder of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We used to use, for example, `getServerSideProps` to redirect to the 404 Page in a page component like so:

```js
// pages/index.js

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const placeId = context.params.placeId;
  const places = await getPlace(placeId);

  if (!places.length) { 
   return {
     notFound: true,
   }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      places[0],
    },
  };
```

With Next.js `13` and the `app` directory, we have Server Components. How redirecting to 404 Page is done as `getServerSideProps` is not used anymore?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation, you could use [`notFound()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found) function as an example as below, and it will render the corresponding [`not-found.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found) file:

```js
// app/user/page.js

import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export default async function Profile({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`/user/${params.id}`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    notFound();
  }
  return <div>Actual Data</div>;
}
```

```js
// app/user/not-found.js

export default function NotFound() {
  return <p>404 Not Found</p>
}
```

If there is no `app/user/not-found.js` file, it uses, `app/not-found.js`. If there isn't `app/not-found.js`, it uses the default one given by Next.js.