# How to do dynamic routes with Next.js and redirect to 404 if route is not found?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm currently trying to make a dynamic route with Next.js 13 with `app` folder, my request is that I want to define some static routes and if the slug does not match with what I put, it'll return a 404 page

Here is what I did with Next version at `13.0.5` and `pages` folder and this was working great, if I'm going to an unexisting page like `/pages/post/foo`, I'm redirected to 404 page

```
// pages/post/[id].tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id, foo } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Post: {id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps = () => ({
  props: {},
});

export const getStaticPaths = () => ({
  paths: [{ params: { id: "abc" } }, { params: { id: "abcd" } }],
  fallback: false,
});

export default Post;
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with `app` folder and this version of Next.js `13.4.4`

```
// app/[locale]/post/[id].tsx
export const dynamicParams = false;
export const generateStaticParams = async () => [{ id: "abc" }, { id: "abcd" }];

const Post = ({ params: { id } }) => (
  <div>
    <p>Post: {id}</p>
  </div>
);

export default Post;
```

But the issue is that it's not working at all, I mean by that that the dynamic route is working but if I try something like `/post/foo`, it's not showing a 404 page
I'm using `next-intl` for the locale change

A solution I thought was to do this

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

const Post = ({ params: { id } }) => {
  if (!['abc', 'abcd'].includes(id)) notFound();

  return (/* ... */);
};
```

But I wanted to know if there was a better solution, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to the 404 Not Found Page in the app folder of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74345219/how-to-redirect-to-the-404-not-found-page-in-the-app-folder-of-next-js)

Comment: That's already what I proposed at the end but I don't know how this works, I mean by that, will the page will be pre-charged with SSR like that and SEO works correctly for `/post/abc` and `/post/abcd` with that solution ? I don't think so :/ Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Yeah, I think as there is no `use client` in the picture, the page will be a pur sever side component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To throw a "not found" page in Next.js using App Router for dynamic URLs, you would do this:

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

type Params = {
  id: string;
};

export default function YourPage({ params }: { params: Params }) {
  // quick for demo purposes
  if (params.id === '123') {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <p>Look at this page, this page is amazing!</p>
  );
}
```

See the official Next.js documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found

Comment: Oh thank you, let's say this is what I have done, now Google Console is telling me that the page won't be indexed because of a redirection, do you know what to do in this situation?

Comment: @Bambou I think that question would warrant its own topic. But 404 pages should not be indexed, generally speaking, so that's a good thing.

Comment: Mmmm IDK because I think that my pages are not indexed because of Next not working correctly, my page not indexed is not a 404 but the page I want to be indexed :/

Answer (score 2):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

You can use a combination of `dynamic` and `dynamicParams` to achieve this effect in combination with a `not-found.tsx` in the folder your route lives at.

```
// [id]/page.tsx

export default function IdPage({ id }: any) {
  return <>Something here...</>;
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return ['1', '2', '3'].map((id) => ({
    id
  }));
}

export const dynamic = 'force-static';
export const dynamicParams = false;
```

Comment: It works fine when launching yarn dev but it doesn't work when doing yarn build with I add `dynamic` and `dynamicParams` :/

Comment: @Bambou What build errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't have build errors but my route is always redirecting to 404 even though it shouldn't with the IDs inside generateStaticParams and I can't figure why

Comment: You may not need `export const dynamicParams = false;`. Based on the documentation, setting dynamic to `force-static` automatically sets dynamicParams to `false`. In my project I had to use both and it might have something to do with the NextJS 13 version. That combination worked for me on version `13.4.19`. I would play around with dynamic/dynamicParams and update the version.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did unfortunately not work, when doing `yarn start`, all pages are 404 (even the pages that should return a status 200) but when doing `yarn dev`, my page is still rendered even with the pages that shouldn't be rendered, now I have issue with Google because they say my page is doing redirection and they can't crawl it :(

Answer (score -3):

If  you are using getStaticProps :

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async ()=> {
    return {
        paths: [], //you can define your paths
        fallback: "blocking"
    }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
   const slug = context.params?.slug as string;
   const posts = getTutorialBySlug(slug) ?? null;

   if (!posts) {
       return {
           notFound: true,
       };
   }

   return {
       props: {
           posts: posts,
       },
   };
};
```

If  you are using get ServerSideProps :

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (
  context
) => {
  const slug = context.params?.slug as string;
  const post = getPostBySlug(slug) ?? null;

  if (!post) {
    return {
      notFound: true, //redirects to 404 page
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you read his question? He is using the new `app` folder of Next.js, where there is none of these function.

Comment: As @YoussoufOumar said, I'm using `app` folder for this one so this will not be working :/